# SQLAlchemy filter Many-to-One - uselist=False

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have following tables:

**Articles**

| id | data_art_no | old_price | new_price | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3353 | 132252 | NULL | 24.5 | 2021-05-07 |
| 2886 | 132252 | 31 | 24.5 | 2021-05-06 |
| 2406 | 132252 | NULL | 31 | 2021-05-05 |
| 1921 | 132252 | NULL | 31 | 2021-05-04 |

**Data**

| art_no | multiplier |
| --- | --- |
| 132252 | NULL |

And this are my models:

```
class Data(Base):
    __tablename__ = "data"

    art_no = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, index=True)
    multiplier = Column(Float)

    article = relationship("Article", uselist=False, order_by="Article.date.desc()")


class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = "articles"

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, index=True)
    data_art_no = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey("data.art_no"))
    old_price = Column(Float)
    new_price = Column(Float)
    date = Column(Date)
```

This should map several articles to a data "element", but in the data element the related article should always be the latest one by id.

However, when I query following:

```
db.query(models.Data).join(models.Article).filter(models.Article.date == Date(2021, 5, 6)).all()
```

I expect to get following return:

```
{ "art_no": 132252, "multiplier": null, "article": { "old_price": 31, "new_price": 24.5 } }
```

However, but I still get the latest article as returned article value:

```
{ "art_no": 132252, "multiplier": null, "article": { "old_price": null, "new_price": 24.5 } }
```

Why don't I get the article I want to get loaded into my Data element? Why is not the Article #`2886` being the Article which is loaded into the Data row?

Comment: First, it looks like you are mis-using the `uselist`, which you most likely can already see as sqlalchemy most likely issues a warning _Multiple rows returned with uselist=False for..._.

However, to make your query work and get what you expect is to hint to SA that your relationship object is already loaded as part of the query by adding this to the query: `.options(contains_eager(models.Data.article))`

Comment: Thanks @van for this solution.